# How to combine two columns of data in R using logical values?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame that describes the VAT status of some farmers in Poland. They either can be a VAT tax payer or a flat rate farmer. The data frame looks something like this:

| VAT tax payer | Flat rate farmer |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | No |
| No | Yes |

What I want to achieve is a column for their VAT status that looks like this and I would like to do this using solutions provided by `tidyverse`:

| VAT_status |
| --- |
| VAT tax payer |
| Flat rate farmer |

How can I do this?

I know that this problem requires the `mutate` function, but I can't wrap my head around what to write inside of it to recognize the logical values inside and convert them into text in the final column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure your example is simplified (or perhaps I have misunderstood), but often times it is easier to accomplish what you need by having your data in a long format instead of wide. Something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

tr <- c("VAT tax payer" = "Podatnik VAT", "Flat rate farmer" = "Rolnik ryczałtowy")

df |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "VAT_Status", names_transform = \(x) tr[x]) |>
  filter(value == "Yes")
```

Or just with `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

tr <- c("VAT tax payer" = "Podatnik VAT", "Flat rate farmer" = "Rolnik ryczałtowy")

df |>
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "VAT_Status",
               values_transform = \(x) replace(x, x =="No", NA),
               values_drop_na = T, 
               names_transform = \(x) tr[x])
```

**Output**

```
  VAT_Status        value
  <chr>             <chr>
1 Podatnik VAT      Yes  
2 Rolnik ryczałtowy Yes
```

---

If you are intent on using `mutate` then you could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(VAT_Status = case_when(
    `VAT tax payer` == "Yes" ~ "Podatnik VAT",
    `Flat rate farmer` == "Yes" ~  "Rolnik ryczałtowy",
    T ~ "Other"
  )
)
```

Note:

1. `T ~ "Other"` will return "Other" for any rows that do not meet the conditions specified. You do not have this in your example, but just in case your real data is more complicated.
2. If you only have two options then you could simply replace `case_when` with `` ifelse(`VAT tax payer` == "Yes", "VAT tax payer", "Flat rate farmer") `` or your Polish values ("Podatnik VAT" and "Rolnik ryczałtowy").

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(across(`VAT tax payer`:`Flat rate farmer`, ~ if_else(. == "Yes", cur_column(), ""))) %>%
  unite("VAT status", `VAT tax payer`:`Flat rate farmer`, sep = "")
#         VAT status
# 1    VAT tax payer
# 2 Flat rate farmer
```

This may not work as desired if there are multiple matches in a row. For that, let's be a little more defensive:

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(across(`VAT tax payer`:`Flat rate farmer`, ~ if_else(. == "Yes", cur_column(), ""))) %>%
  unite("VAT status", `VAT tax payer`:`Flat rate farmer`) %>%
  mutate(`VAT status` = gsub("^_|_$", "", `VAT status`))
#         VAT status
# 1    VAT tax payer
# 2 Flat rate farmer
```

Key differences:

- not specifying `sep=""` restores to its default `sep="_"`;
- if there are multiple columns with "yes", then they will be concatenated, separated by `_`, but since we have empty strings where there is no "yes", we start or end with `"_"`, so the `gsub` removes those

If you need to translate those names to something else, one technique is to use a named vector as a "dictionary" of sorts:

```r
xlate <- c("VAT tax payer" = "Podatnik VAT", "Flat rate farmer" = "Rolnik ryczałtowy")
quux %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(. == "Yes", cur_column(), ""))) %>%
  unite("VAT status", `VAT tax payer`:`Flat rate farmer`) %>%
  mutate(
    `VAT status` = gsub("^_|_$", "", `VAT status`),
    `VAT status` = stringr::str_replace_all(names(xlate), xlate)
  )
#          VAT status
# 1      Podatnik VAT
# 2 Rolnik ryczałtowy
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list("VAT tax payer" = c("Yes", "No"), "Flat rate farmer" = c("No", "Yes")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't be able to come up with this myself. Thank you!

Comment: What if I want to generate the values inside the "VAT status" column independently from the previous two column names? In the file I'm working on the column names are "vat_tax_payer" and "flat_rate_farmer", while the values inside the "vat_status" column should be "Podatnik VAT" and "Rolnik ryczałtowy" (Polish translations of the names of the original two columns).

Comment: See my edit for a quick translation